# How to update a view in every specific time of frame

Tags: android, android-view, frame-rate

Currently i am using recursive invalidate() calls and i don't know if this code will run **at fixed rate in every phone**. Below you can see my code here. Is Handler approach a better and reliable one? How can i make certain that view update speed will be fixed in every phone?

```
 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);

if(action){
    checkCollisionDetection();
    rotateAngle = rotateReverse ? rotateAngle - levelRotateSpeeds[level-1] : rotateAngle + levelRotateSpeeds[level-1];

    canvas.rotate(rotateAngle,CoordinateUtils.centerX,CoordinateUtils.centerY);
    invalidate(); //this is the recursive approach
}else
    canvas.rotate(rotateAngle,CoordinateUtils.centerX,CoordinateUtils.centerY);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect,markerRoundSize,markerRoundSize,paint);
```

}

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`